# jQuery DataTables plugin with JSON data source taking multiple POST requests on global search

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

Friends,

I'm using jQuery [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin. I'm doing the Server Side Processing with JSON datasource to fill the DataTable as showing in the [example](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)

Here's my code

#### HTML

```
<Table class="projectGrid DataTable display" id="tblList" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th align="center">
            Created
        </th>
        <th align="center">
            Assigned
        </th>
        <th align="center">
            Stage
        </th>
        <th align="center">
            Priority
        </th>
        <th align="center">
            Status
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th align="center">
            Created
        </th>
        <th align="center">
            Assigned
        </th>
        <th align="center">
            Stage
        </th>
        <th align="center">
            Priority
        </th>
        <th align="center">
            Status
        </th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    <asp:Repeater ID="reptList" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <%#Eval("CreatedBy")%>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <%#Eval("AssignedTo")%>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <%#Eval("Stage")%>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <%#Eval("Priority")%>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <%#Eval("Status")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</tbody>
</table>
```

#### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data =
{
    datatableConfig: {
        "aaSorting": [],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: "~/IssueData.asmx/GetIssueList",
            type: "POST"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "0" },
            { "data": "1" },
            { "data": "2" },
            { "data": "3" },
            { "data": "4" }
        ]
    }
}

$(data.datatable + ' tfoot th').each(function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('hidden')) {
        $(this).html('<input type="text" class="footerInput" style="width:' + ($(this).width() - 10) + 'px" placeholder="Filter ' + $.trim(title) + '" />');
    }
});

// Apply Datatable
if ($(options.datatable).length) {
    table = $(options.datatable).DataTable(options.datatableConfig);
}

// Apply the search
table.columns().every(function () {
    var that = this;

    $('input.footerInput', this.footer()).on('change', function () {
        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
            that.search(this.value).draw();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Everything is working fine, except Search. When I enter single letter in a Search, It raises 3-4 Ajax POST Requests. Any Idea why it processes more POST requets on single keypress event?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to apply search so when user press 'enter' key ajax request is made to search :

```
// Apply the search
table.columns().every(function () {
    var that = this;

    $('input.footerInput', this.footer()).on('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && $.trim(this.value) !== '') {
            that.search(this.value).draw();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting..  How to apply this on Global Search?

Comment: For applying it on global you have to unbind key press event of datatable search using $('#tblList').find('.filter-input').unbind(); where "filter-input" is class of search input field. and after it you have to bind keyup event of is as : $('#tblList').delegate('.filter-input', 'keyup', function (e) { if (e.keyCode === 13 && $.trim($(this).val()) !== '') { table.api().search($(this).val()).draw(); } });